# changing colors in barh(stacked)

Tags: python, plot, bar-chart

I have one table with regions (y axes) and in x values. Each region has two bars.
I would like to change colors. I would like that each little bar in barh has a different color.
I have this code where colors repeat:
For example after pink I would like another color, not red again.It is possible to change the colors scale? using for example "tab10"
Furthemore, it is possible to get legend where each color outline one year (2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,2018,2019)

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib

matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')

plotdata = pd.DataFrame({
    "2010_y":[0.63,0.56,0.89,0.94,0.68,0.63,0.34,0.54,0.77,0.77,0.86,0.42,0.49,0.70,1.12,1.10,0.30,0.67,0.30,0.23],
    "2011_y":[1.10,0.54,0.94,0.81,0.80,0.87,0.90,0.99,0.53,0.78,0.98,0.99,0.87,1.09,1.18,0.89,0.89,0.70,1.05,0.86],
    "2012_y":[1.39,0.97,0.98,0.99,0.95,1.10,1.07,1.10,1.02,1.05,0.97,0.92,0.94,0.91,0.85,1.22,1.24,1.08,1.08,1.01],
    "2013_m":[1.86,1.34,1.12,1.25,1.26,1.08,1.31,1.58,1.22,1.26,1.37,1.14,1.23,1.00,1.13,1.49,1.14,1.37,1.25,1.23],
    "2014_m":[1.59,1.04,1.03,1.10,1.44,1.43,1.33,1.81,1.56,1.22,1.08,1.36,1.11,0.87,1.10,0.68,1.31,1.26,1.25,1.61],
    "2015_m":[0.71,1.14,1.18,0.99,0.87,0.74,0.91,0.57,0.79,1.09,1.16,0.89,1.15,0.98,1.24,0.75,0.85,0.83,1.02,0.71],
    "2016_m":[0.67,1.22,1.00,0.96,0.97,0.96,0.95,0.79,1.06,1.04,0.83,1.06,1.07,0.98,0.66,1.06,0.99,1.13,1.03,1.05],
    "2017_m":[0.68,0.84,0.73,0.73,0.79,0.98,0.80,0.54,0.85,0.91,0.55,0.65,0.86,0.71,0.71,0.77,0.95,0.80,0.81,0.87],
    "2018_m":[0.74,1.28,1.21,1.13,0.99,1.00,1.21,0.97,1.07,0.91,1.38,1.34,1.25,1.65,1.28,0.97,1.11,1.09,1.20,1.13],
    "2019_m":[0.63,1.07,0.92,1.10,1.24,1.21,1.18,1.10,1.12,0.97,0.80,1.24,1.04,1.11,0.74,1.06,1.23,1.07,1.01,1.30]
    }, index=["ABR", "BAS", "CAL", "CAM", "EMR","FVG","LAZ","LIG","LOM","MAR","MOL","PIE","PUG","SAR","SIC","TOS","TAA","UMB","VDA","VEN"]
)
plotdata3 = pd.DataFrame({
    "2010_y":[4.12,1.44,5.73,3.91,3.43,0.00,4.26,0.00,1.95,2.65,0.00,4.82,3.61,2.17,3.05,2.66,0.00,2.86,3.00,1.15],
    "2011_y":[0.00,0.39,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.32,0.00,0.00,1.02,0.00,2.72,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.83,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00],
    "2012_y":[0.08,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00],
    "2013_m":[0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.45,0.00,0.00,2.58,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.90,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.51,0.00,0.00],
    "2014_m":[0.05,0.03,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.40,0.00,0.01,0.00,0.00,0.42,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00],
    "2015_m":[1.45,0.16,0.27,0.09,0.64,1.68,0.20,2.42,0.47,0.41,0.28,0.32,0.09,0.93,0.18,0.52,0.00,0.67,0.00,0.00],
    "2016_m":[0.00,0.89,0.00,0.00,1.11,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.44,0.00,0.03,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.22,0.00,0.00],
    "2017_m":[0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.95,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.09,1.85,0.00,0.00,0.11,0.00,0.07,0.35,0.00,1.74,0.00,0.00],
    "2018_m":[0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.06,0.00,0.11,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.25,0.00,0.00,0.01,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00],
    "2019_m":[0.30,3.09,0.00,0.00,0.34,0.00,0.42,0.00,1.48,0.25,0.00,0.58,0.19,0.00,2.44,0.46,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.85]
    }, index=["ABR", "BAS", "CAL", "CAM", "EMR","FVG","LAZ","LIG","LOM","MAR","MOL","PIE","PUG","SAR","SIC","TOS","TAA","UMB","VDA","VEN"]
)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
#stacked_data = plotdata.apply(lambda x: x*100/sum(x), axis=1)
#stacked_data2 = plotdata2.apply(lambda x: x*100/sum(x), axis=1)
#stacked_data3 = plotdata3.apply(lambda x: x*100/sum(x), axis=1)

stacked_data.plot(kind="barh", stacked=True, width=0.4, 
                  ax=ax, position=0, edgecolor='black')
#stacked_data2.plot(kind="barh", stacked=True, width=0.25, 
                  # ax=ay, position=1, hatch='//',edgecolor='black')

stacked_data3.plot(kind="barh", stacked=True, width=0.4, 
                   ax=ax, position=1,edgecolor='black')
ax.get_legend().remove()
ax.set_ylim(top=len(stacked_data)-0.1)
#ax.set_xlim(right=len(stacked_data)-0.5)
ax.set_facecolor('xkcd:white')
# displaying the title
plt.title("titla")
# set various colors
ax.spines['bottom'].set_color('black')
ax.spines['top'].set_color('black') 
ax.spines['right'].set_color('black')
ax.spines['left'].set_color('black')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify your colormap when plotting. Also use different colormaps for your barplots if you like, for example:

```
stacked_data3.plot(kind="barh", stacked=True, width=0.4, 
                   ax=ax, position=1,edgecolor='black', cmap='Accent')
```

A list of available colormaps is available on [matplotlib.org](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html#qualitative)

Comment: And for legend, do you have some idea?I tried to put legend, but repeat each time, twice the value of 2010, 2011, 2012, etc.

Comment: If you keep the same colormap for both plots, you can activate the legend with the kwarg `legend=True` and disable it with `legend=False` (enable only one legend and it should work)

Comment: I have another question, but if I wanted in x the years, in y (left) the regions and in y (right) values, it is possible to create a plot with lines?

Comment: How would you set regions on the y-axis? Do you mean separate plots? I suggest you take a look at [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html?highlight=lineplot#seaborn.lineplot). It can plot pretty much anything